# No resource identifier found error while trying to run app in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a newbie to Android and also Android Studio. I have done the following:

I have  created a folder named `libs` in my root project. In my `libs` folder lies the `cardslibrary`. I am using this library in my app. My xml file is as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout    
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

   <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
     android:id="@+id/carddemo"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     card:card_layout_resourceID="@layout/card_thumbnail_layout" />
```

When I try to run the app I am getting the following errors:

```
Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'card_layout_resourceID' in package 'com.example.root.card_demo'
Error:(13, 38) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'card_layout_resourceID' with value '@layout/card_thumbnail_layout').
```

I think the way I am using the namespace is incorrect. But after going through certain posts also I am not able to figure out what is wrong. Kindly guide me step by step.

Comment: try to integrate the card lib via gradle, `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'` in the build.gradle depencies of your app module

Comment: The error still persists

Comment: have a look on this great tut, cardview is provided by google itself, you do not need the lib provided by gmariotti http://treyrobinson.net/blog/android-l-tutorials-part-3-recyclerview-and-cardview/

Comment: did you add that library to the project?

Comment: I have added the library

Answer (score 0):

once i got the same issue in android studio.. when i added the package name in the place of `res-auto` at line `xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`, it solved the issue.

That is `xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/your_package_name"`

You can give it a try..!!

Comment: U mean package name of my application in which the library is included?

Answer (score 0):

You must add the module ( cardlib.core ) in the project , be sure to see if the project properties you are linking modules of the library. for me it worked .
greetings .